# My asp.net application times out authentication even though I have time outs set in .config

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I must be doing something wrong. I have followed instructions to set the timeout on my forms authentication app, but the app never renews the cookie and will time out about every 15mins or so.
I must be missing something that is so obvious it is not mentioned in the literature.
Here is my config info:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" />    
 </authentication>
```

and the session state

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="120">
  ...
```

I have tried sliding or not sliding--same time out happens. 
Dumb questions: do I need something in the code behind (VB) on every page to make sure the postback renews the authentication?

Comment: I think you need to set your session time out as well.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859309/session-end-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: sorry, forgot to add my code for that. Yes, it is set (edited post)

Comment: have you tried assigning the `cookieless` setting in the `SessionState` tag?

Comment: it is optional and defaults to usecookies anyway, so don't think that is it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(vs.80).aspx

Comment: Checked cookies, everything looks. I timed it and it is 20 minutes, regardless of my settings. It has to be the iis hosting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are browsing your web application from IIS then check the check the Idle Time-Out(minutes) property under "Process Model" of application pool.

If it is 20 minutes. You should change that property value.